# Create and Send Zip file -NODE JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, zip

I'm trying to create and then send zip file to client. I know how to create it but I've got a problem with send it to client. I tried many ways. 
I'm sending POST request from Client and as response I want to send a file.
This is my server-site example code

```
var Zip = require('node-zip');
router.post('/generator', function(req, res, next) {
    var zip = new Zip;

    zip.file('hello.txt', 'Hello, World!');
    var options = {base64: false, compression:'DEFLATE'};
    fs.writeFile('test1.zip', zip.generate(options), 'binary', function (error) {
        console.log('wrote test1.zip', error);
    });
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test1.zip');
    res.download('test1.zip');

}
```

});
 I also tried something like this:

```
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
```

I tried to use such libraries as:

1. node-zip
2. archiver

Can anyone explain me how to do that ?

Comment: Hi @PtDf, did you got the solution? I am also stuck in such situation. I am not able to download the zip file. Please let me know if you solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

This module works fine too: https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip

Example without creating temporary zip file in server:

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
router.get('/zipFilesAndSend', function(req, res) {
    var zip = new AdmZip();
    // add local file
    zip.addLocalFile("./uploads/29/0046.xml");
    // get everything as a buffer
    var zipFileContents = zip.toBuffer();
    const fileName = 'uploads.zip';
    const fileType = 'application/zip';
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${fileName}"`,
        'Content-Type': fileType,
      })
    return res.end(zipFileContents);
});
```

Comment: This is the better solution for me. Ideal if you don't want a sub-folder which you will get with express-easy-zip

Comment: Hello, It's better for me too this solution, but what about the front to donwload this ? thanks

Comment: @ALFA you just browse to the '/zipFilesAndSend' path and the file will be downloaded at the browser

Comment: @golimar , my case is on post and not get :). I use something like this : .then(response => response.arrayBuffer()) and try to download the response buffer

Comment: @golimar I got the solution simply using the downloadjs , thanks

Answer (score 4):

I haven't worked with node-zip or archiver before (I usually just use the built-in zlib module), but one thing I noticed right away is that you should place `res.download` inside the callback of `writeFile`. That way it will only send the file once it has been fully written to disk.

```
fs.writeFile('test1.zip', zip.generate(options), 'binary', function (error) {
    res.download('test1.zip');
});
```

I hope this solution works for you, if it doesn't feel free to comment.

Also, I think `res.download` sets the Content-disposition header for you, you don't need to set it manually. Not 100% sure on that one though.

Comment: It dosent work. I did as you wrote. But as response i got some dumb text in browser console output.

Comment: Did you check the file `test1.zip` to see if it actually contains what you want it to contain?

Comment: Yes it contains hello.txt. In browser console output i can see hello.txt and some dumb text. I'm trying to do it local, this may have some impact ?

Comment: Hang on a sec, you're downloading a file but you're checking it in the browser console? I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do. Downloading a file like that is when you want to save the file to your harddisk. If you just want to send data to the browser, you should use `res.send` instead. Could you perhaps edit your original post and explain a bit what you're trying to achieve, what you want to do with the data you send to the client?

Comment: Yes i would like to downloading the file on my hard disk after I send by POST some data. I did everything like you wrote but downloading doesn't start. Forgot about the console output it doesn't matter.

Comment: Then to track down the problem, you could log your app and your data every step of the process and see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Try this express-easy-zip [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-easy-zip) package **to generate a zip file from a local folder path** and send it **as a download** to the client.

```
var zip = require('express-easy-zip');
var app = require('express')();

app.use(zip());

app.get('my-route/zip', async function(req, res) {
    var dirPath = __dirname + "/uploads";
    await res.zip({
        files: [{
            path: dirPath,
            name: 'Package'
        }],
        filename: 'Package.zip'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

Above solutions work.(above solutions generate zip and send it to frontend as data in response. In order to make it as downloadable following code will work) I was using [express-zip](http://express-zip). It is compressing files and sending data to frontend from backend(node). But in frontend I was getting only data in response. In my case I want user can be able to download the zip which sent by server. To solve this I followed following approach. For generating **download** window in browser i used [downloadjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs) (we can follow another approach but i find this easy)

**Front-End**

```
const download = require('downloadjs')
return axios({
        url:process.env.API_HOST+'/getuploadedfiles',
        method:'get',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            withCredentials:true,


        },
        responseType:'arraybuffer' // If we don't mention we can't get data in desired format
    })
    .then(async response => {
        console.log("got al files in api ");
        let blob = await new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/zip' }) //It is optional

        download(response.data,"attachement.zip","application/zip") //this is third party it will prompt download window in browser.

        return response.data;
    })
```

**Backe-End**

```
const zip = require('express-zip');
app.use('/getuploadedfiles',function(req,res){
     res.zip([
    {path:'/path/to/file/file2.PNG',name:'bond.png'},
    {path:'/path/to/file/file1.PNG',name:'james.png'}
])
```