# Single fetch-request and get multiple response from Server with express

Tags: javascript, image, express, fetch, client-server

Can someone help me with the easiest way to change my code to receive multiple replies? I want to be able to send multiple images at once.

I have this on the client side:

```
fetchUsers.addEventListener("click", function() {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/users")
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(image => {
      var create_img = document.createElement("IMG");
      create_img.setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(image));
      document.getElementById("imageDiv").appendChild(create_img);
      console.log(image);
    });
});
```

And this on the server side:

```
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  res.set({
    'Content-Type': 'image/png'
  });
  res.sendFile("C:/Users/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot.png");
  //res.write("C:/Users/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot.png");
  //res.end();
  res.status(200);
});
```

It works if I just send one picture. I would like to be able to send several pictures, but I don't know exactly how the client-server agreement should be, since I'm still a beginner.

Comment: That's not how HTTP works, each request only gets one reply.

Comment: You could combine multiple images in a zip file.

Comment: maybe you have a simple example that is something like my code. So with fetch and express?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260789/create-and-send-zip-file-node-js